# Clearing the textarea after changing the value

Tags: javascript

I am selecting a text on textarea and replacing it with newtext "shan"..The problem when I click on the submit button still the old text is submitted instead of new text..

But this problem doesn't come when I press spacebar on keyboard and then press Submit button..

I can see the replaced text in "TextArea" but when I submit it the only the old text gets submitted..

```
     var replacement text="shan";
    if (window.getSelection) {
       sel = window.getSelection();

    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        var e1=range.startContainer;
        var e2=e1.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
        e2[0].value=replacementText;
            e1.focus();
        }
     }
```

Comment: you have `var replacement text-="shan";`  then `value = replacementText`, which one is it?

Comment: Isn't `var replacement text-="shan";` a syntax error? How is that code called? (If it's on submit then I'd expect the syntax error to stop the rest from working so it would be submitted with the old value.)

Comment: Edited it..The text gets replaced in the textarea but when I submit it only the old text gets submitted..

Comment: Are you using any plugins that would affect the text area?  Also, post your DOM.

Comment: Also, how are you submitting the form/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax Error?

```
var replacementText = "shan";
if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();

    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        var e1 = range.startContainer;
        var e2 = e1.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
        e2[0].value=replacementText;
        e1.focus();
    }
}
```

### Other things to look at or update your question with...

How are you submitting the form?

Do you have the textarea named appropriately so that it will get sent back to the server properly?  Are you getting the value out properly via javascript(if thats how you are posting back)?

Have you checked the post info with Fiddler or Firebug or Chrome to see what the request actually looks like?

Comment: Thanks..it's working fine now ..I checked the element and there was a hidden field after the TextArea..So added this value too e2[1].value=replacementText;